# System wide rocker gesture for Ubuntu

Tags: software-recommendation, shortcut-keys, xev

Is it possible to add system wide rocker gesture for Ubuntu?

Rocker gesture is basically a following sequence of events :

```
ButtonPress event: mouse1
ButtonPress event: mouse3
ButtonRelease event: mouse3
```

This should trigger on focused window:

```
KeyPress event: XF86Forward
KeyRelease event: XF86Forward
```

And the reverse to get a `XF86Backward` event.

How can I add this functionality?